# Remove Pin to Start Option on Just Desktop Recycle Bin in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, recycle-bin

I keep accidentally hitting the "Pin to Start" option when I go to empty the Recycle Bin. Is there some registry key I can use to just remove that specific option from the context menu?

[image]

Comment: The registery that handles this feature would effect all shortcuts on your desktop.

Comment: The Microsoft developers should remove this by default. This is bugging me even with Windows 10 for years. Hope dies with Windows 11 or 12. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to remove it just from the "Recycle Bin" using a little workaround:

1. Take the ownership of these two keys -

   > HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\shell\empty

   (Owned by "NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller")

   > HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\shell\empty\command

   (Owned by "SYSTEM")

   `{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}` is the class ID of the "Recycle Bin".
2. Grant yourself full permission.
3. Rename the KEY "empty" to "pintostartscreen".
4. Eventually, restore the ownerships

This should overwrite the "Pin to Start" verb

5. By chance, Windows will partly generate a new "empty" entry. You can take the ownership of this KEY and remove all permissions in order to block the second menu entry for good.

Comment: Works also on Win 10.

Answer (score 2):

The article [How to Add or Remove "Pin to Start" Context Menu for Files in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15624-pin-start-files-windows-8-a.html)
suggests as solution to delete the registry key of :

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\pintostartscreen
```

The article
[How To Disable Pin To Start Screen Feature In Windows 8](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-disable-pin-to-start-screen-feature-in-windows-8/) suggests using the application
[AutoPin Controller](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.168) for similar options (however it is not clear from the documentation whether it does what you want).

Comment: Looks like this will remove the "Pin to Start" context menu entry from **every file**.

Comment: My comment was just meant as a word of caution, to clear things up. The title also specifically mentions "just the Recycle Bin" but this level of control probably isn't possible. On a related note, I'm not sure this works since the Recycle Bin is a special folder. Kirk probably has to remove the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\pintostartscreen` branch to make it [vanish](http://www.eightforums.com/customization/11480-pin-start-recycle-bin-menu.html) from a folder's context menu.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here are a bit too invasive for my taste so here is a way to do it without deleting/renaming anything and you don't even need administrator rights!

This will hide the verb for the current user:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Folder\shell\pintostartscreen]
"AppliesTo"="NOT System.ParsingName:=\"::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\""
```

(save as .reg and double-click)

Change HKEY_CURRENT_USER to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE if you want to apply it to all users.

Comment: Doesn't work in Win 10.

Comment: The registry setting below seems to work on Windows 10. (Note: makes the item do nothing for the Recycle Bin, but does not HIDE the item, which seems like a bug in Windows.)


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\PintoStartScreen]
AppliesTo = System.ParsingName:<>"::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}"

The main difference is "shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\PintoStartScreen" rather than "shell\pintostartscreen".

The AppliesTo syntax is different only because I based it on what MS themselves use in the related "shell\pintohome" under the same folder class/key.

Answer (score 1):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\shell\pintostartscreen]

"MUIVerb"=" ‎"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\shell\pintostartscreen\command]

@="rundll32"
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

;For Windows 11 & 10 after updates
;Microsoft have changed the Pin to start from "pintostartscreen" to CLSID {a2a9545d-a0c2-42b4-9708-a0b2badd77c8} to stop us from removing this annoying thing

;Work around is to put an empty space so you don't click it accidentally
;if you want the useless create shortcut rename "link" to anything else
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\shell\link]

;No name
"MUIVerb"=" "

;No icon (needed only if you add an icon and want to remove it)
"Icon"=-

;Disabled (grayed)
"CommandStateHandler"="{E9571AB2-AD92-4ec6-8924-4E5AD33790F5}"

;Seprators lines before and after if you want
"SeparatorBefore"=""
"SeparatorAfter"=""

;Don't add or it will not work
"Position"=-
"Extended"=-
"ProgrammaticAccessOnly"=-
"LegacyDisable"=-

;Recycle Bin icon
;"Icon"="imageres.dll,-54"

;Second solution: Uncomment below to remove Pin to start from all folders
;[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellEx\ContextMenuHandlers\{a2a9545d-a0c2-42b4-9708-a0b2badd77c8}]

;Remove Pin to quick access form Recycle Bin context menu if its there
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\pintohome]
"AppliesTo"="System.ParsingName:<>\"::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\" AND System.IsFolder:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True"

;For older Windows or you can use the rename empty method
;[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}\shell\pintostartscreen]
;"MUIVerb"="‎ "
;"CommandStateHandler"="{E9571AB2-AD92-4ec6-8924-4E5AD33790F5}"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).